# Error when querying with AGE: no relation entry for relid 3

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I have a graph that contains two kinds of nodes: one is to represent customers and other for merchants and stores. The graph keeps track on where and how much the customer spent on a store, representing this interaction with edges. Here is how I'm creating them:

```sql
-- Customers
CREATE (Bobby :Person {id:'1', name:'Bobby', gender:'man', age: 72})

-- Merchants
CREATE (Amazon :Merchant {id:'2', name:'Amazon', street:'2626 Wilkinson Court', address:'San Bernardino, CA 92410'})

-- Transaction
CREATE (Bobby)-[:HAS_BOUGHT_AT {amount:'986', time:'4/17/2014', status:'Undisputed'}]->(Amazon)
```

When I want to retrieve only the dates of the purchases in descending order, it successfuly returns them:

```sql
SELECT * FROM cypher('MyGraph', $$
    MATCH (v)-[r :HAS_BOUGHT_AT]->(m)
    WITH toInteger(split(r.time, '/')[0]) as month, 
         toInteger(split(r.time, '/')[1]) as day, 
         toInteger(split(r.time, '/')[2]) as year
    RETURN month, day, year
    ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC, day DESC
$$) AS (month agtype, day agtype, year agtype);

 month | day | year 
-------+-----+------
 12    | 28  | 2014
 12    | 26  | 2014
 12    | 24  | 2014
 12    | 23  | 2014
 12    | 20  | 2014
 12    | 20  | 2014
 12    | 20  | 2014
 12    | 20  | 2014
 12    | 16  | 2014
 12    | 15  | 2014
 11    | 28  | 2014
 11    | 27  | 2014
 11    | 14  | 2014
 10    | 25  | 2014
 10    | 15  | 2014
```

But if I want to show the names of the vertices that are being matched, it throws an error instead.

```sql
SELECT * FROM cypher('MyGraph', $$
    MATCH (v)-[r :HAS_BOUGHT_AT]->(m)
    WITH toInteger(split(r.time, '/')[0]) as month,
         toInteger(split(r.time, '/')[1]) as day,
         toInteger(split(r.time, '/')[2]) as year
    RETURN month, day, year, v.name, m.name
    ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC, day DESC
$$) AS (month agtype, day agtype, year agtype, v_name agtype, m_name agtype);

ERROR:  no relation entry for relid 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are not passing on **v** and **m**. So you cannot access them after WITH.

The below query resolves your error.

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
    MATCH (v)-[r :HAS_BOUGHT_AT]->(m)
    WITH v,m,toInteger(split(r.time, '/')[0]) as month,
         toInteger(split(r.time, '/')[1]) as day,
         toInteger(split(r.time, '/')[2]) as year
    RETURN month, day, year, v.name, m.name
    ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC, day DESC
$$) AS (month agtype, day agtype, year agtype, v_name agtype, m_name agtype);
```

Result:

```
 month | day | year | v_name  |  m_name  
-------+-----+------+---------+----------
 4     | 17  | 2014 | "Bobby" | "Amazon"
(1 row)
```